# Multiple column Union Query without duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I'm trying to write a `Union Query` with multiple columns from two different talbes (duh), but for some reason the second column of the second `Select` statement isn't showing up in the output.  I don't know if that painted the picture properly but here is my code:

```
Select empno, job
From EMP
Where job = 'MANAGER'
Union
  Select empno, empstate
  From EMPADDRESS
  Where empstate = 'NY'
  Order By empno
```

The output looks like:

```
EMPNO   JOB
4600    NY
5300    MANAGER
5300    NY
7566    MANAGER
7698    MANAGER
7782    MANAGER
7782    NY
7934    NY
9873    NY
```

Instead of 5300 and 7782 appearing twice, I thought `empstate` would appear next to `job` in the output.  For all other `empno`'s I thought the values in the fields would be `(null)`.  Am I not understanding `Unions` correctly, or is this how they are supposed to work?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the data in a separate column you will want a `JOIN` not a `UNION`:

```
Select e.empno, e.job, a.empstate
From EMP e
left join EMPADDRESS a
    on e.empno = a.empno
Where job = 'MANAGER'
    AND empstate = 'NY'
Order By e.empno
```

A `UNION` combines the two results into a single set but the data is listed in the same columns. So basically they are placed on top of one another:

```
select col1, col2, 'table1' as src
from table1
union all
select col1, col2, 'table2' as src
from table2
```

Will result in:

```
col1 | col2 | src
t1   | t1   | table1
t2   | t2   | table2
```

If you want to have the data in a separate column which is sounds like you do then you will use a join of the tables.

Comment: Okay, I figured the join would work but I am trying to self teach myself SQL which means I was trying to come up with different ways to use `Unions` lol. So when it comes to `Unions`, if I want to see other columns I am going to get duplicates? Also thank you once again bluefeet for your assistance, I feel like I should be paying you a teachers salary.

Comment: A `UNION` will remove any duplicates, a `UNION ALL` will leave the duplicate rows of data.  It depends on what you are trying to do with the data as to whether or not you want to use a `UNION` or a `JOIN`. For this case you would use a `JOIN`

Comment: Adam, just accept @bluefeet 's answer, and he'll receive additional points as a salary :-)

Comment: @WolfgangFleischmann Lol it looks like thats how I am going to have to pay him :).

Answer (score 1):

Bluefeet has the correct answer.

Think of joins as combining tables horizontally - you're adding more columns to the original query with each table you join.

Think of unions as stacking record sets vertically - you're adding extra rows to the same set of columns.

Comment: Hmm that was a great way of explaining it, it definitely helped me understand the difference a little more.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a JOIN for this..

```
Select e.empno, e.job, ea.empstate
From EMP e LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPADDRESS ea ON e.empno = ea.empno
Where e.job = 'MANAGER'
And ea.empstate = 'NY'
Order By e.empno
```

UNION is for taking 2 result sets with the same column names and merging them into one. In your example, its lumping column 2 (job and empstate) together, and taking the name from the first select.

Answer (score 0):

i think you meant to write is as a join instead?

ie if you wanted empstate to be null for those employee's not in NY.

```
select empno, job, empstate
from emp e
     left outer join empaddress a
                  on a.empno = e.empno
                 and e.empstate = 'NY'
where e.job = 'MANAGER';
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to fully understand `Unions` but I guess in this case I was attempting something that wasn't going to work from the get go.  Thank you for your response and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

this one works in oracle..by using union ..here inner query will fetch out the all the columns after that grouping with empno and rest of the columns is string concatenated

```
  select EMPNO
        ,wm_concat(job) job
        ,wm_concat(EMPSTATE) EMPSTATE 
  from 
  ( select EMPNO,job,'' as EMPSTATE  from EMP Where job ='MANAGER'
    union  select EMPNO,'' as job, EMPSTATE from EMPADDRESS Where empstate ='NY'
  )
 group by EMPNO order by 1
```